# Right way to implement schedule / cron

Tags: php, apache, cron, user-permissions, pimcore

I need to add bulk objects creation in Pimcore. First I tried with web, but due to big size of set, Request taken long time and approach discarded in practical terms.

Then I chosen cron for schedule the jobs for later period, But I get other issue. Like some other RAD application pimcore generate some of code automatically in some folders like /website/var/versions. So these folder automatically get permission of web user ( in my case apache user ).

But My cron script run by normal user which execute Pimcore API calls for object/data creation but unable to write in folders due to insufficient permissions. Now I can have one of two options.

1. Run cron through apache user, which is big no for security reasons.
2. Give writable permissions ( chmod 777 like or add my user to apache group by using chown ). But pimcore create new folders time by time when managed from browser. So these new folders do not have permissions to write by cron script ( permission is max 755, I get for new folders which is not enough for group write ).

I searched previously on google and found command setfacl for setup default user / permissions for a folder. Which I used like this.

```
    `sudo setfacl -Rm u:apache:rwx,d:u:apache:rwx website/var/versions/object`
```

But it regular failed and I need to give manually permission again and again.

Now if any practical approach for fixing this ?

Note : I am currently using Amazon Linux AMI. But it can be later change to redhat or ubuntu, So Its better is a universal linux solution is available.

Comment: "Run cron through apache user, which is big no for security reasons." - I am curious, why do you think it is?

Comment: @chluehr, We have seen practical example of system hack through apache cron on a busy site before.  That is enough reason for system administrators to disable apache cron.

Comment: ok i see, sure - though in my opinion this boils down to securing the php scripts that are to be run via a cron script. There is no inherent / unavoidable danger in doing this. Your mileage may vary :-)

Comment: @chluehr Actually running cron as apache itself have huge security hole, As hacker can easily add his script to apache user cron, which is only available web user at that time. Securing php script will not prevent this. Only other way to prevent this to update server to keeping any exploting new issues in server installed packages ( including apache/php/mysql )

Comment: We should possibly stop here - how can a hacker "easily" add a script? and where is the difference to adding a script to the docroot?

Comment: @chluehr, "easily" may be wrong word. But as practically seen by myself, their are a shell script running from apache cron that downloading some binary files from hacker's website. Even we remove multiple time that cron entry it is added again after sometimes (Obviously he/she taking advantage of some exploit ). Then system admin disable the cron. There after no binary files detected on same system.

Comment: So the problem is the exploit, not the cron. Disabling the cron just migitated the usage/effect. I understand.

Answer (score 2):

Pimcore already requires that its maintenance jobs (cron) are run under apache user, so not running your job under apache user might not improve things much.

But you might want to go with the approach that is used for the integrated newsletter sending.

See **/pimcore/modules/reports/controllers/NewsletterController.php:194**:

```
$cmd = Tool\Console::getPhpCli() . " " . realpath(PIMCORE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "cli" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "send-newsletter.php"). " " . escapeshellarg($letter->getName()) . " " . escapeshellarg(Tool::getHostUrl());
            Tool\Console::execInBackground($cmd, PIMCORE_LOG_DIRECTORY . "/newsletter--" . $letter->getName() . ".log");
```

Above code runs the CLI script **/pimcore/cli/send-newsletter.php**

With this approach the cron is not needed and since the job is run as CLI it won't timeout (if you didn't explicitly set the timeout for PHP CLI).

Comment: If this script run by CLI, Still it should need user, which will not have permissions to write on versions folders which have permission only for apache user, Am I right ?

Comment: No, it will run under the Apache user, so it should have all the rights that you need. PHPs shell_exec command runs the CLI scripts under current user - so if you run it from controller action it's run by your Apache user.

Comment: Still security problem, Shell functions are also disabled.

Comment: Pimcore uses shell_exec in multiple places. Pimcore\Tool\Console::execInBackground() is actually using the shell_exec. But if you have it turned off and your system is still running fine, then I can think of only one other way, which is to use a similar approach to how Pimcore is doing batch jobs in grid view. So by splitting the job into multiple batches and then using AJAX calls to process the batches. (for example select few objects in the grid view, right click and select Delete objects).

Comment: My first choice was with Http request but due to nature of request ( which is bulk insertion and take lot of time ), Apache need long connection / request completion time. this reason also discarded job queue idea which we are using for other schedule jobs.

Comment: Then using a queueing system like beanstalk (with turned on queue persistence)  would be your best bet: https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk